# iterating over index of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose we have a table of (for simplicity)historical stock data, which has columns like

```
timestamp   ticker open high low close
```

and I want to have a column which has the percentage return for ticker on the date.

Now, the obvious first step is make a multi-index of timestamp and ticker, and then for each ticker one can do something like:

```
df.loc[idx[:, ['AAPL']], idx['ret']]=df.loc[idx[:, ['AAPL']], idx['close']].pct_chg()
```

What is not clear is how to iterate over the tickers in the most elegant way possible. One can make a list of tickers, and just do a plain python for loop, iterating the above over all of them, but this seems a little clunky. is there a more "pandas" way of doing this?

To answer the comment, for simplicity, let's just have the close, and suppose the data looks like

```
date ticker close
Jan 1 A     10
Jan 2 A     20
Jan 3 A     30
Jan 1 B     15
Jan 2 B     15
Jan 3 B     7.5
```

The result should be

```
date  ticker close return
Jan 1 A       10    NaN
Jan 2 A       20    1.0
Jan 3 A       30    0.5
Jan 1 B       15    NaN
Jan 2 B       15    0
Jan 3 B       7.5  -0.5
```

Comment: `Now, the obvious first step is make a multi-index of timestamp and ticker,`, not obvious, and not really the first step. I'd like to see 5-10 rows of some sample data along with your expected output.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ See edit.

Comment: Got it, and I have your answer. However, you want the pct_change for each ticker and each date right? In your output, it seems like you only want the pct_change per ticker.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I want the daily pct_change for every ticker (so morally, the way to think of it is as a collection of dataframes, one per ticker, each datetime-indexed).

Comment: Okay, my answer should be enough then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like a simple `groupby` + `pct_change` call should be enough.

```
df['return'] = df.groupby(['ticker']).close.pct_change()
df

    date ticker  close  return
0  Jan 1      A   10.0     NaN
1  Jan 2      A   20.0     1.0
2  Jan 3      A   30.0     0.5
3  Jan 1      B   15.0     NaN
4  Jan 2      B   15.0     0.0
5  Jan 3      B    7.5    -0.5
```

Alexander raised a good point in the comments. Your data should be sorted by date and ticker for this operation to make sense. If it isn't, make a `sort_values` call *first* -

```
df = df.sort_values(['date', 'ticker'])
```

Comment: Truly you are wise in the ways of science :)

Comment: @IgorRivin Behold the power of providing input and expected output when asking a question!

Comment: Just ensure that the data is first sorted by date or by ticker and date.